# Why are my if statements not working correctly?

Tags: c++

When answered with the first question, if you put in 1962, for example, it comes up with "Close but its 1969" instead of "Wrong, it 1969".

In fact, putting anything, including the 1969, which is the right answer, still outputs "Close but its 1969".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <list>
#include <unistd.h>
        
using namespace std;

void Neil_Question_year(){
    double Neil_year_answer;
    std::cout << "Welcome to questionaire game." << endl;
    usleep(1500000);
    std::cout << "Starting off with Neil...";
    usleep(2000000);
    std::cout << "\nWhat year was he born?: ";
    std::cin >> Neil_year_answer;

    if (Neil_year_answer == '1969')
    {
        cout << "\nSeems about right.";
    }
    else if (Neil_year_answer == '1968' or '1967' or '1970' or '1971'){
        cout << "\bClose but its 1969.";
    }
    else if(Neil_year_answer != '1968' or '1967' or '1970' or '1971')
        cout << "\bWrong, its 1969.";
}

void Neil_Question_month(){
    usleep(180000);
    std::cout << "\nNext question....";
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "\nStarting in 5..." << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Starting in 4..." << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Starting in 3..." << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Starting in 2..." << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Starting in 1...\n" << endl;
    usleep(1000000);

    std::cout << "\bWhat month was he born in?";
}

int main(){
    Neil_Question_year();
    Neil_Question_month();
}
```

Comment: And, `'1968' or '1967' or '1970' or '1971'`, too. Please consider reading a [good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of random coding.

Comment: You have *two* errors: First you attempt to compare a `double` variable with a *character* value; Then the logical `or` operator doesn't work as you expect. You seem to have skipped quite a few classes of school, or many chapters in your text-book. Don't do that and end up guessing about things.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, it should be `1969`.

Comment: @MikeCAT is correct.  `Neil_year_answer` is a `double`, so `'1969'` should be changed to `1969`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `'1969'` is a multiple-character character constant and its value is implementation-defined. You should write like `1969` withput `''` to express numbers.
- You cannot use `or` like that. You should write comparision one-by-one or use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for defining sets to find from.
- Your second `else if` looks redundant because it seems intended to just check for negate of previous condition.

One-by-one comparision:

```cpp
if (Neil_year_answer == 1969)
{
    cout << "\nSeems about right.";
}
else if (Neil_year_answer == 1968 or Neil_year_answer == 1967 or Neil_year_answer == 1970 or Neil_year_answer == 1971){
    cout << "\bClose but its 1969.";
}
else {
    cout << "\bWrong, its 1969.";
}
```

Using `std::set`:

```cpp
std::set<double> close_set = {1968, 1967, 1970, 1971};
if (Neil_year_answer == 1969)
{
    cout << "\nSeems about right.";
}
else if (close_set.find(Neil_year_answer) != close_set.end()){
    cout << "\bClose but its 1969.";
}
else {
    cout << "\bWrong, its 1969.";
}
```

Note that a condition like  `1967 <= Neil_year_answer and Neil_year_answer <= 1971` will behave differently from the conditions above. For example, they will behave differently when `Neil_year_answer = 1969.5`.

Comment: I'm a beginner to C++ well any programming language at all, watching: https://youtu.be/vLnPwxZdW4Y  that to teach me, thanks for the help, but why is my question  -3 and banned for asking other questions for 2 more days? I thought this was what Stackoverflow was for.

Answer (score 3):

You have `Neil_year_answer` of type `double` while you compare it with `'1968'`, which is a [multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). The same goes for all other clauses. A [multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal):

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
> multicharacter literal . A multicharacter literal has type int and
> implementation-deﬁned value.

Looks like you should set `Neil_year_answer` to be `unsigned` and make direct checks against integer literals. For example:

```
unsigned Neil_year_answer;
cin >> Neil_year_answer;
if (Neil_year_answer == 1969) /* do the processing */;
```

Next, your use of the logical operator won't give you the desired logic. You have to do it like in the following form:

```
if (Neil_year_answer == 1969 || Neil_year_answer == 1970 || Neil_year_answer == 1971);
```

Where this:

```
if (Neil_year_answer == '1968' or '1967' or '1970' or '1971')
```

**Will always yield true**, since even if the `Neil_year_answer == '1968'` part is wrong, the next `'1967'` **is not 0**, hence **not false**. Thus, the logical operator returns `true`.

Comment: `'1969'` is not an integer literal.